# Calling a web service from T-SQL (Stored Procedure) using MSXML

Tags: sql-server, web-service, ole-automation

[image]

```
EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objectID, 'send', null, @requestBody 
    IF    @hResult <> 0 
    BEGIN
          EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objectID, @source OUT, @desc OUT
          SELECT      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = 'Send failed', 
                MedthodName = @methodName 
          goto destroy
```

When I Call a web service Through Sp IN SQl Server In Above Mention I'm getting error as Shown In The Pics

Comment: Well it looks like you can't connect to the server right? are you sure it works when you call it from outside sql server (like using soapui)?

Comment: @TomV Yes you are Right Suppose in Case If My Server service is not Started how can I send request from Sql with out such error

Comment: If your server isn't running I don't understand how you could send a request to it without error

Comment: OK Is Their Any Alternative How Can I Save The Data Whose Sending is getting Fail

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about that exact error, but I would advise against using the OLE Automation stored procedures (i.e. `sp_OA*`) as they have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 was released and have various "issues".

I you need to interact with a Web Service, your best bet is to use SQLCLR. I have more info regarding this option in the following answer, also here on DBA.SE:

[Bringing web service data into SQL server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149292/bringing-web-service-data-into-sql-server/149349#149349)